# Best 4-color palette for dithering arbitrary images

Tags: graphics, dithering

While 8 or 16 colors can offer a relatively satisfying result of dithering, 4 color palette results varies. Below are some acceptable results.

[image: Raw]
BBC micro mode 2 8 colors [image: BBC micro mode 2 8 colors]
NES 4 color full screen [image: NES 4 color full screen]
CGA mode 04h Bright 2 [image: CGA mode 04h Bright 2]
via https://8bitworkshop.com/dithertron/

So what 4-color combination can give the best color fidelity without knowledge of image input? Or more specifically, which four colors can provide the greatest coverage of color-space and can offer even distribution of possible colors in that color-space with, say, 4x4 matrix Ordered Dithering algorithm?

---

Comment: The problem can be reduced into both optimizing the posture **then** maximizing the volume of a **Tetrahedron** into a #RRGGBB **Cube** with all 4 vertices **inside** the cube, which has to be it since the limitation of circuitry(or were there a **workaround back in the day** allowing the expansion of brightness range?). The first impression came to me which would be RGBW, but that failed to cover bright Cyan, Yellow and Magenta thus not seems very convincing to me. Maybe a little rotation would be better?

[image]

Comment: [graphicdesign.se]?

Comment: see also https://github.com/zeroeth/shiver_me_dithers . . . this is retrocomputing, no reason for the question to be closed. IBM PC had 4 color CGA and this is an obvious question for anyone porting software to that system.

Answer (score 5):

<s>This seems nominally Retrocomputing, because there were plenty of computers that only offered a 4-color palette - or even just 2-color - at times. However, without reference to an actual production system, I'm skeptical that there were many, if any, practical systems using *arbitrary* colors in a small palette.</s> *See below for an actual implementation - Apple IIGS.*

Typically a 4-color palette used 4 system-defined colors, with no easy way to change them. For example, [IBM CGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#320%C3%97200) had a 4-color 320x200 display mode. In this mode, each palette/intensity selection, which applied to the entire screen, used 4 colors from the standard 16-color system palette. Each 4-color palette included 3 fixed selections (green/red/yellow, cyan/magenta/white or cyan/red/white) plus one more color from the 16, which defaulted to black. You picked a mode and palette for your software from what you had available, and that was that. No tweaking of the R vs. G vs. B.

Later cards such as EGA allowed for selection of each color in a palette. However, those same cards typically skipped over the 4-color modes. For example, [EGA modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Graphics_Adapter#Modes) included 640x350x2 (monochrome has its advantages at times in terms of speed and memory usage) and then jumps to 16 colors at various resolutions.

In the hypothetical sense of "what would be best", logically a 4-color palette matching the native mode of the device would be best. Which for most consumer devices from the past 40 years means:

- Red, Green, Blue, Black for monitors
- Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, White for printers

In each case, all other colors are built up from the primary colors, including white on monitors or black (except really a muddy gray) for printers (which is why printers normally have 4 colors - CMY + black (K) - but that would be a minimum of 5 colors - Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black, White (no ink)). *Except as pointed out in a comment, if you fill in a monitor at native resolution with an even mix of red pixels,green pixels and blue pixels, you get an overall "white" effect (at high enough resolution, at least) but really a muddied (possibly colorful, depending on the monitor and resolution) gray because it will be at ~ 1/3 the native white brightness of the monitor.

In fact, with printers it generally is a binary mode for each color - you can increase resolution or change the printed dot size, but you really can't say "50% cyan, 25% magenta, 10% yellow". On monitors it is different as both CRT and LCD monitors can vary the intensity of each pixel.

---

##### [Apple IIGS to the rescue!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_IIGS#Video_modes)

A bit of poking around and I found that the Apple IIGS includes a 4-color user-defined palette. According to Wikipedia, it included:

> 640×200 (4 colors, selectable from 4,096 color palette)

Presumably (I haven't verified, but nothing else makes sense) the 4,096 color palette is 4-bits (16 levels) for each of Red, Green, Blue.

That being said, if I had absolutely no advance knowledge of the contents of an image, I'd still go for Red, Green, Blue, Black as the universal 4-color palette. There *may* be some advantage to a particular intensity of Red vs. Green vs. Blue based on human vision, type of monitor, etc. but full intensity Red, Green and Blue plus Black (i.e., #FF0000, #00FF00, #0000FF, #000000) is certainly the easiest way to go.

Comment: I would think it fairly likely that at least some machines with 4-color graphics would have used something like a 4x4 register file to turn a two-bit index into a 4-bit color selector, since doing so would take much less circuitry than approaches like those in the CGA, while offering much more versatility.  The 4x4 register file chip is used on the IBM PC motherboard, so it would have been familiar to at least some computer designers of that era.

Comment: @supercat Possible? Yes. Did anybody actually implement it? I don't know. Searched more.. Apple IIGS

Comment: I think the Bally Astrocade allowed arbitrary four-color palettes, as would arcade machines like Missile Command.  Not sure how they were implemented, though.  There were lots of 8-bit computer designs, so it's hard to know all the designs they used.

Comment: Electronika BK-0010 used the fixed red-green-blue-black palette.

Comment: @LeoB. Interesting. According to Wikipedia, some later models actually had a bunch of selectable palettes - making it a little more like some other systems. And PDP-11 compatible  - interesting!

Comment: The BBC and Electron offer any four out of the TTL eight in four-colour modes; the Amstrad CPC offers any four out of 27 (i.e. 3*3*3); the Enterprise any four out of 256; the Sam Coupé any four out of 128…

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Worse yet, the later Electronika BK models had a timer interrupt tied to the frame sync, facilitating techniques to switch palettes in the middle of a frame in demos, and maybe even some games.

Comment: The Amiga can use arbitrary colour depth settings including 4-colour (out of 4096) mode. It's most commonly used for the Workbench (desktop GUI) to save RAM and reduce the amount of time the graphics co-processor takes control of the CHIP RAM bus, blocking the CPU from accessing it (important on stock Amigas with no FAST RAM).

Comment: IMHO RGBW offers more color space than RGBK. RGB can only mix into dark gray in a 4x4 matrix. The brightness range is very narrow. The same applies to CYMW vs CYMK.

Comment: @Schezuk Monitors produce light in primary colors - on a CRT they are separate spots (see "shadow mask" and also Sony Trinitron to see how this works) - white on a monitor is not literally all 3 dots on top of each other - it is 3 tiny colored dots next to each other, all on at the same time. LCD displays produce the backlight separate from the color but the colors are again little things next to each other - so W is "light all the R, G and B in an area" - and you get W. In fact, if you have a 4-color RGBK palette at full device native resolution (640x480 or 1280x1024 or whatever) then

Comment: the black and the RGB==W colors will be identical to what they would be with a full RGB range. What you lose is the ability to make shades of RGB. Printing is a little trickier because CMY is not "same as black" in the same way that on a monitor "RGB is same as white".

Comment: You've got it wrong. It's about the palette. Dithering doesn't add up or deduct colors; it mixes into a medium tone. When you pick the Red color, it means you turn off 2 other channels, and reduce the brightness. You cannot make up the brightness by trailing another green pixel and another blue pixel which both turn off 2 channels, unless you turn up the brightness of monitor by 3x.

Comment: Oops. Actually I think the truth is a bit of a mix. But you're right that I'm getting confused a bit between *all* Red + *all* Green + *all* Blue, which would result in *all* White; and 1/3 Red, 1/3 Green, 1/3 Blue (which is all you'd get with my 4-color palette) which may actually appear "white" (provided it is high enough resolution) but would at best really be a colorful gray because it would be ~ 1/3 intensity. But RGBW instead of RGBK doesn't fix things because now you can't get black.

Comment: *8 colors = 3 bits* really makes things tremendously easier because then you get black + RGB + CMY + white - which at a high enough resolution can get simulate anything (within the color gamut of the monitor). But that needs 3 bits. Which isn't the question, and which I don't know if I've seen - 4 bits - often RGB + intensity but can also be a selectable palette, is very common. 3 isn't a power of 2 so we don't see it so much.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact 3 bit planar graphics make a little more sense if you have 16 bit wide data bus and RAM to work with, but yes otherwise not so much.

Comment: Atari ST with 4 out of 512 at 640x200 would be similar.